# Data is disappearing from UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am building an iOS app with a custom tab bar at the top. When i click on the home icon, I want it to show a tableview directly below the tab bar. Currently my code does just that, however the data doesnt show correctly. If I limit my Cells to 4 or less (in the numberFoRowsInSection), the data will show, if i have like say 15 cells, the data shows for a split second and then it disappears. I have been looking at tutorials all over the place and everything seems to be correct, the data will show correctly in a stand alone view(like i created a similar to a singleview application in the story board and made that the initial view). I dont know where i am wrong. Below is my code in implementation file of the tableviewContoller class:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 4;//this works... but change to 15 it doesnt work
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
  PrayerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSLog(@"cell is Nil"); //never hits this
    cell = [[PrayerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
}

//the data showing is the correct data that i want to see
cell.dName.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"displayname"];
cell.priority.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"priority"];
cell.dateTime.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"datetime"];
cell.numPraying.text = @"2 praying";
cell.requestPreview.text = [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"request"];

NSLog(@"created cell") //verify cell was made

return cell;
}
```

Here is my PrayerCell.H file

```
@interface PrayerCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *requestPreview;
@property (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *dName;
@property (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *dateTime;
@property (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *numPraying;
@property (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *priority;

@end
```

I made no Changes to the prayerCell.M file

if you need me to post any other code blocks/screenshots please let me know.

Comment: You may want to verify the frame of the tableView - e.g. just add an `NSLog(@"tableview frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(tableView.frame));` within your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation.

Comment: What do you mean "home icon"? May be home button? You show tableview when app going to pass to background? Right?

Comment: Please add `PrayerCell` code and a screenshot link.

Comment: I suspect you don't understand how cell are recycled in a table view -- it's fairly convoluted at first glance.  Once a cell rolls off the screen iOS deletes it, and your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` needs to be prepared to reconstitute it when asked for it.

Comment: I note that you're missing a declaration for "cell" in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Is there perhaps some code you omitted?

Comment: I have added my updated code to the post. here are some screen shots
http://imgur.com/a/7oX67
The first is of my root screen. ideally i would like every other screen to open where the green box is. the second is what is currently happening.

Comment: when i have it as its own thing, like it is not opening in the green view, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The cell should not be an ivar, it should be a local variable. You also need to dequeue the cell in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
```

Comment: I have added that to the code above. I forgot to include it in my posting.